# C# Blackjack Game

Tags: c#, blackjack

I want to make my blackjack game give me a new card when i press my button Draw A Card (hit)

```
    private void btnDraw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rdn = new Random();
        int YourCardOne = rdn.Next(1, 10 + 1);

        this.lblYourCardOne.Text = Convert.ToString(YourCardOne);
```

This is the code i have to draw one card, i want it to draw another card when i press the button again but i don't want it to change the first one.

I tried doing this but it changed both cards whenever i pressed draw,

```
private void btnDraw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rdn = new Random();
        int YourCardOne = rdn.Next(1, 10 + 1);

        this.lblYourCardOne.Text = Convert.ToString(YourCardOne);

        Random rdn1 = new Random();
        int YourCardTwo = rdn.Next(1, 10 + 1);

        this.lblYourCardTwo.Text = Convert.ToString(YourCardTwo);
```

Comment: you only need one Random for the entire game.  Using Rand that way wont emulate a deck of cards at all.  BJ uses more than just 2 cards, you need to allow for a 3rd,4th, 5th even 6th card.  Currently your click code is for the first 2 cards, not for Hitting.  That code should be for Deal.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead you could use a list of ints for your hand

You could make your hand like this:

```
List<int> hand = new List<int>();
```

Then when the button is clicked add to the list:

```
private void btnDraw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random rdn = new Random();
    hand.add(rdn.Next(1, 10 + 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to try and mimic the real world, instead of trying to apply programing patterns to your game. Don't use a list of cards and randomly pick one. You don't do that in a game of Blackjack, you always take the top card. Which means you should have a single `Shuffle()` method that randomly mixes up the cards, and one that takes the top card off.

Here's some example code I had from a gard game I did when I was just learning to program that may give you an example of what I mean for the shuffle. After that, the act of getting the top card is straight forward.

```
int deckSize;

public void Shuffle()
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    //Swap every card with a random card in the deck
    for(int count = 0; count < deckSize; count++)
    {
        int index = rand.Next(deckSize);
        Card swapee = cards[index];
        cards[index] = cards[count];
        cards[count] = swapee;
    }
}
```